# Get index of repeated char in string

Tags: c#

I have a textbox which contains the text "aaaaaa". If I select any "a" with the mouse it returns index of selected text. However I allways get zero for that index.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.SelectedText));
}
```

**can anyone help me to get the real index ?**

Comment: And how do you "select any a"?

Comment: So you want the index where the `SelectedText` exists in the textbox?

Comment: Select it with the mouse and click the button

Comment: yes , such as when i select the fifth 'a'  the index must be = 4

Comment: Well of course you cant use IndexOf :) MSDN:`Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string within this instance.`

Comment: But it is searching text -  textBox1.Text.  People get criticized for not posting what they tried - it does not work but you posted what you tried.

Comment: thanks guys . i got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is the [`TextBox.SelectionStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  That will give you the index in the text box where the selection starts.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = textBox1.SelectionStart.ToString();
}
```